# Como puedo impersonar un usuario en C#

Tags: c#, sql, conexión

como mencione en la pregunta me gustaria impersonar un usuario para poder usar ese usuario en algunas tareas en especifico ya que es necesario utilizar los permisos que contiene el usuario que utilizare para impersonar.
Mil gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Por lo que he entendido tu conexión funciona, quieres coger otro usuario con autentificación de Windows (¿en el sql server?) y te coge automáticamente el de l'ordenador. Para que podamos adaptarlo tendrías que subir el código que tienes hecho hasta ahora  [ejemplo de microsoft para impersonar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8.1#System_Security_Principal_WindowsIdentity_Impersonate)

Comment: No me parece un camino adecuado. Impersonar es hacer cosas en nombre de otro....feo. Existen otras alternativas. Que dependen de tú escenario. Y la más simple, que es, usar un login sql server.

Comment: @rexxarcat sí lo que quiero es coger otro usuario con autenticacion de windows pero esto en c# ya que quiero utilizar los permisos de ese usuario para todos los usuarios que utilizan la aplicacion ya que ninguno podria con su usuario original

Comment: Entonces no tenes que impersonar.. tenes que crear un usuario en SQL server, y conectarte con ese usuario y listo.. tenes un usuario de la APP, que se conecta con ese usuario....

Comment: @gbianchi si seria la mejor solucion pero dado que no puedo crearlas yo no es una opcion ya que necesito solicitar su creacion y el proceso es demasiado tardado, y la cuenta que tengo es de servicio y es con la que quiero trabajar

Comment: Si quieres impersonar, entonces, supuestamente tienes el usuario y contraseña, de lo contrario no vas a poder impersonar a nadie. Quizá este link te ayude https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8.1

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Claro que sí, yo tengo el usuario y contraseña... pero ya pude resolver mi problema igualmente muchas gracias por su apoyo

Comment: Deberias ingresar la solución que hiciste de modo tal que pueda servir de apoyo a quien pudiera tener el mismo problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno primero que nada a todos los que me ofrecieron su apoyo, ya pude resolver mi problema para impersonar un usuario... primero que nada creé una clase donde vendra una funcion de LogOnUSer que intentara iniciar sesion con el usuario local, el cual recibira usuario(el que se tratara de impersonar), contraseña y dominio el cual si tiene exito recibira un token el cual tendra identificador para hacerse pasar por el usuario especificado.

```
public class Impersonalizacion
        {
            private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
            private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;


            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);
            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint ="DuplicateToken", ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, int ImpersonationLevel, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);


            public static WindowsImpersonationContext WinLogOn(string strUsuario, string strClave, string strDominio)
            {
                IntPtr tokenDuplicate = new IntPtr(0);
                IntPtr tokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);

                if (LogonUser(strUsuario, strDominio, strClave, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref tokenHandle))
                    if (DuplicateToken(tokenHandle, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                        return (new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate)).Impersonate();
                        return null;
            }


        }
```

Y por ultimo solamente es llamar la clase, ingresar el usuario a impersonar, su contraseña y dominio... ademas es importante garantizar que se produzca el Undo al terminar de realizar la tarea con el usuario impersonado aunque haya alguna excepción de por medio dentro del código que se está impersonando ya que al terminar esa tarea todavia se estara ejecutando el programa con los privilegios del usuario impersonado, y no necesariamente con el usuario que estaba ejecutando la aplicación anteriormente.

```
WindowsImpersonationContext _objContext = null;
                Console.WriteLine(QuienSoy());

                _objContext = Impersonalizacion.WinLogOn("UsuarioImpersonado", "Contraseña", "Dominio");


            if (_objContext != null)
            {
                try
                {                    
                 //Aqui va el codigo a ejecutar con el usuario impersonado
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");                        
                }                
                finally
                {
                   //Se deja de utilizar el usuario impersonado 
                    _objContext.Undo();
                }

            }
                    Console.WriteLine(QuienSoy());
            }

            internal static string QuienSoy()
            {
                return WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para eso tienes que activar el usuario de Windows en el servidor de bases de datos.

En SQL Management Studio accedes a *(SERVIDOR) -> Seguridad ->Inicio de sesión*. Haces click con el botón derecho del ratón  y escoges *Nuevo inicio de sesión*.

Una vez en el cuadro de dialogo configurar un nuevo inicio de sesión con el usuario de Windows que quieras que acceda a tu base de datos.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: No es esto el problema.. OP quiere entrar a la DB con otro usuario, no el que esta logueado.. y ese usuario tiene permisos...

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).